# in a postgres container, where are the imported extensions located?

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

i would like to create a volume on that directory, and bring in plpython and postgis extensions.

for some reason i am unable to create extensions from within a container.

i have tried to run the postgres container by using the local version and just connecting to it, since the local one has the extensions...but to no avail.  \dx shows nothing.

i know that in `/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension` i can find `plpython3u.control`

which has the following:

```
# plpython3u extension
comment = 'PL/Python3U untrusted procedural language'
default_version = '1.0'
module_pathname = '$libdir/plpython3'
relocatable = false
schema = pg_catalog
superuser = true
```

but i cant find what it's referring to...

my error, after i went inside the container and made that file:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;
FATAL:  extension "plpython3u" has no installation script nor update path for version "1.0"
server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
```

Comment: What container image are you using? The default `postgres:14` image doesn't have the `plpython3u` extension. If you're building your own, please include your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @larsks i was using the default, and then had a need for the extension...

Comment: @larsks i even copied ```/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib/plpython3.so``` into the container...no bueno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres extensions are implemented as shared library modules (`.so`) files, generally located in `/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib`. So for example, the control file for the `plpgsql` extension (`/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/plpgsql.control`) looks like this:

```
# plpgsql extension
comment = 'PL/pgSQL procedural language'
default_version = '1.0'
module_pathname = '$libdir/plpgsql'
relocatable = false
schema = pg_catalog
superuser = true
trusted = true
```

In the `module_pathname` value, `$libdir` refers to `/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib`, where we find `/usr/lib/postgresql/14/lib/plpgsql.so`.

---

If you want to enable a new extension, like `plpython3u`, you need both the control and sql files as well as the shared library (which needs to be built for the Postgres version that you're running).

Fortunately, it looks like the `plpython` extension is already packaged and installable using the stock `postgres` image. The following `Dockerfile` will produce an image that has the `plpython` extension installed:

```
FROM postgres:14

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install postgresql-plpython3-14 && \
    apt-get clean all
```

If we build an image from that `Dockerfile`:

```
docker build -t postgres-plpython .
```

And then start a container:

```
docker run -d --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret postgres-plpython
```

We can `docker exec` into the container and add the extension to a
database:

```
$ docker exec -it postgres psql -U postgres
psql (14.3 (Debian 14.3-1.pgdg110+1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create extension plpython3u;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

Comment: brilliant.  how did you find that it was prepackaged?  is it something similar of postgis?

Comment: I figure it was prepackaged by running `apt update` and `apt search plpython` (and then installing the package and verifying that it was functional). For postgis, I would look at the official postfix image: https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/postgis/postgis/